# JQuery .append() to multiple places in single forloop Python Django

Tags: python, jquery, django

I have a chat application and messages either are classified as `outgoing` or `incoming`.

Client-side, these messages are shown on either side of the chat, depending on whether they are sent or received.

[image: example]

I am trying to use the Jquery `.append(msgText)` to echo the message when it is sent or received (like the above image shows) but cannot get it to echo in the right place with the correct formatting (it only shows up after a page refresh but I want it to echo in real time).

I've tried targeting `var sentMsg = $('#sent_msg')` with `#sent_msg` as id within the forloop, but it obviously just appends the sent text to every single sent message.

If I put it outside of the forloop (ex) `var chatHolder = $('#chat-items')`, then the problem is that there is no formatting on the left and right-hand sides...all messages (sent and received) just come through on the left side in an unordered list.

Is there a way to append to each new iteration of the forloop and also apply the proper formatting/styles?

I'm learning the ropes here so would appreciate any input.

thread.html

```
 <ul id="chat-items">
            {% for chat in object.chatmessage_set.all %}
            {% if chat.user == user %}
<div id="sent_msg">
            <div class="outgoing_msg">
              <div class="outgoing_msg_img"> <img src="{{ chat.user.profile.image.url }}" alt="sunil"> </div>
              <div class="sent_msg">
                <p>{{ chat.message }}</p>
                <span class="time_date"> {{ chat.timestamp }}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
</div>
            {% else %}
<div id="incoming_msg">
            <div class="incoming_msg">
              <div class="incoming_msg_img"> <img src="{{ chat.user.profile.image.url }}" alt="sunil"> </div>
              <div class="received_msg">
                <div class="received_withd_msg">
                  <p>{{ chat.message }}</p>
                  <span class="time_date"> {{ chat.timestamp }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
</div>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
```

base.html

```
<script>
    // websocket scripts - client side*
    var loc = window.location
    var msgInput = $("#id_message")
    var chatHolder = $('#chat-items')
    var incomingMsg = $('#incoming_msg')
    var sentMsg = $('#sent_msg')

    // below is the message I am receiving
    socket.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log("message", e)
      var chatDataMsg = JSON.parse(e.data)
      incomingMsg.append('<li>' + chatDataMsg.message + ' from ' + chatDataMsg.username + '</li>')
    }

    // below is the message I am sending
    socket.onopen = function(e) {
      console.log("open", e)
      formData.submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        var msgText = msgInput.val()
        sentMsg.append(msgText)
        var finalData = {
          'message': msgText
        }
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(finalData))
        formData[0].reset()
      })
    }
```

[image: result]

Comment: I see you're appending the incoming messages to `incomingMsg`, which is defined as `$('#incoming_msg')`. But I see no such ID in your template snippet? (I do see such a class though.) I must be missing something though because if this was the only error the messages wouldn't appear anywhere, and the JS would be throwing errors.

Comment: Sorry I didn't keep a lot of that in since it wasn't appending correctly, I did have `div id="incoming_msg"` and the same for `sent_msg` but it was obviously adding on the sent text to every single message

Comment: could you edit your question to show more of your HTML? I'm afraid I can't figure out what might be going wrong without being able to see the element that you're telling the browser to add the incoming messages to.

Comment: Done! I've added in `<div id="sent_msg">` after `{% if chat.user == user %}` and added an image as to where that `no` text is appending.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't see anything with id `incoming_msg`. That's where the incoming messages should be getting added, according to your JS code?

Comment: @RobinZigmond Okay I've added it and an image of what that results in, as in having both `<div id="incoming_msg">` and `<div id="sent_msg">` where I've placed them in the code.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not sure I can really see what's going wrong - but that edit has made it clear you have the same id multiple times on the page. (Because it's inside a `for` loop in the template.) That isn't valid HTML and will likely break any Javascript that relies on the ID.

Comment: Ah yes obviously!! Okay thank you for that, I mean I could change it to `var sentMsg = $('.sent_msg')` to target the div but that still wouldn't format them properly?

Comment: If I add them to the div class, they just get sent below every message, so there is a loop of the same text.